# Angular2 - Attribute directive for a custom input component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a component called `<app-craftinput>`. I'm using this on different layouts.

The template is:
`<input type="text" name="" value="" class="input__field input__field--type1">`

What is the best method to add attributes like `<app-craftinput [value]='23' [label]='Email'></app-craftinput>` in the component's template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

child .component.ts:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class app {

@Input() value:number;

}
```

parent .component.html:

```
<app-craftinput [value]="3"></app-craftinput>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

in order to utilize the information passed from the parent in your child element, in child .component.html:

```
<label for="{{value}}">{{value}}</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! But how it will work if I'll have a 'label' in the template and I want to add it to the component? (and display it, of course)

Comment: @MihaiGota is this label within the app-craftinput element?

Comment: Is within the component template. Something like: `<label for="">Name</label> <input name="test" class="" />`.